# Drupal Slideshow small image at bottom

Tags: drupal-7, view, slideshow, photo-gallery

I have made a image gallery with a strip of thumbnails and 1 fullsize image.

(when a thumb is clicked, the images is loaded full size):

[image: drupal 7 views slideshow]

The problem is the little thumbnail underneath the full size view...
I dont know where this is coming from...

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to check *Exclude from display* for the FIELD holding the thumbnail images:

[image]